# how to replace $ with \$ in a string in java

Tags: java, regex

I have tried a few things but breaking the problem down, I have this half working...

```
String msg = "my cool $ stuff"
String newMsg = msg.replaceAll("\\$", "h");
```

resulting in "my cool h stuff"

My real goal is to have it be "my cool \$ stuff"

it keeps blowing up with capturing errors though.  I can't seem to escape it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a regexp here:

```
String msg = "my cool $ stuff"
String newMsg = msg.replace("$", "\\$");
```

Answer (score 4):

Without any regex you can do:

```
String repl = "my cool $ stuff".replace("$", "\\$")
//=> my cool \$ stuff
```

If you must use regex then it will be:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\$0");
```

i.e. `\\\\` will be used to place a single `\` in replaced string.

Comment: This works because [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) takes a `char` as an argument, but [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) takes a regular expression so that `$` no longer is no longer problematic.